# Decryption function: 'int' object is not callable

Tags: python

I've written code for a function that executes decryption of individual characters. I received this error message: 'int' object is not callable, but I don't know which object this is referring to and how exactly I'm illegally calling something. What did I do wrong? Thanks.

```
def affine_cipher_decryption(ch,N,alphabet):
    M = len(alphabet)
    A = get_smallest_co_prime(M)
    A_inverse = multiplicative_inverse(A,M)
    counter = -1
    for element in alphabet:
        if element == ch:
            counter += 1
            index = counter
            break
        else:
            counter += 1
    cipher_index = A_inverse(index-N) % M
    cipher_ch = alphabet[cipher_index]
    return cipher_ch
```

Here is the error traceback message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       runfile('/Users/brandononeil/Documents/SS18proj04.py', wdir='/Users/brandononeil/Documents')
>
> File
>   "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py",
>   line 880, in runfile
>       execfile(filename, namespace)
>
> File
>   "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py",
>   line 102, in execfile
>       exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
>
> File "/Users/brandononeil/Documents/SS18proj04.py", line 161, in
>   
>       main()
>
> File "/Users/brandononeil/Documents/SS18proj04.py", line 148, in
>   main
>       decr_ch1 = affine_cipher_decryption(ch, rotation, ALPHA_NUM)
>
> File "/Users/brandononeil/Documents/SS18proj04.py", line 101, in
>   affine_cipher_decryption
>       cipher_index = multiplicative_inverse(A,M)(index-N) % M
>
> TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Also, here are the contents of `multiplicative_inverse`:

```
def multiplicative_inverse(A,M):
    for x in range(M):
        if (A*x)%M == 1:
            return x
```

I've already tried renaming `A_inverse`, and I've tried writing the contents of the `multiplicative_inverse` function inside of `affine_cipher_decryption` (so I wouldn't have to call `multiplicative_inverse`) to no avail.

Any ideas of what else could be wrong?

Comment: The error traceback message points out exactly where the error is.  Please edit your question to include this message.

Comment: What does `multiplicative_inverse(A,M)` return?

Comment: Change `multiplicative_inverse(A,M)(index-N) % M` to `(multiplicative_inverse(A,M)*(index-N)) % M`

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is these two lines:

```
A_inverse = multiplicative_inverse(A,M)
cipher_index = A_inverse(index-N) % M
```

`A_inverse` is set to the result of `multiplicative_inverse` which I'm assuming returns an `int`. The second line tries to call a function named `A_inverse` but the local variable shadows the function in the scope.

You can fix it by renaming either the local variable or the function.

Comment: I've tried changing the naming conventions to no avail, and I even tried coding in the contents of multiplicative_inverse so I don't have to call the function. The program continued to return the same error. I will edit the question to include the error traceback message and the contents of relevant function. I'm still not sure what's wrong?